# Prove that $\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx$.
I have observed in some places that the following is done:

Letting $t=x+c$, then we have the corresponding differentials $dt=dx$, and so $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_{t(a)}^{t(b)}f(t-c)\,dt=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(t-c)\,dt$

However, I do not understand why they say that t=x+c and if the demonstration is correct.

Any help? thanks

Comment: The bounds of integration change according to $t(b)$ and $t(a)$ so you want to choose a $t$ which will result in $b+c$ and $a+c$. Note that the constant part is immaterial when calculating the differential.

Comment: Can it be said to be a result of applying the method of integration by substitution?

Comment: Yes this is integration by substitution.

Comment: The meaning of the integral on the left is the area under a curve in a certain interval. By introducing $c$, you shift the curve and the interval to the left or to the right. But the area under the curve remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rephrasing of the change of variables formula, which says that $$\int_{\varphi(\alpha)}^{\varphi(\beta)}f(x)dx=\int_{\alpha}^\beta f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)dt$$ for $\varphi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ continuous. We like to think about this formula as "we replace the variable $x$ by the variable $\varphi(t)$", so here writing "let $t=x+c$" is the short way for writing "we apply the change of variables formula for $\varphi(t)=x=t-c$, $\alpha=a+c$ and $\beta=b+c$".

Comment: In other words, the demonstration is reduced to the application of the method of integration by variable substitution?

Comment: Yes, all is about finding the good $\varphi$ to get the desired outcome in your integral.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can prove that with first and second fundamental theorem of calculus.
How $f$ is continuous for the first fundamental theorem of calculus we have that exists a primite $F$ of $f$.
If we denote by $g$ to the funtion that $g(x):=x-c$ we have by the chain rule that:
$(F \circ g)'(x):=F'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)=f(x-c)$.
So $F \circ g$ is a primite of $f(x-c)$ and we have by the second fundamental theorem of calculus that:
$\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)dx=(F \circ g)(b+c)-(F \circ g)(a+c)=F(b)-F(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$.